# Spring Exception Handling not working using ExceptionHandler Class

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception

I tried to add an ExceptionHandler class to my Spring Rest program using this class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class Handler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchSellerException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ExceptionObject> handleNoSuchSellerExcpetion(NoSuchSellerException ex,
                                                                       WebRequest req){
        ExceptionObject exo = new ExceptionObject(ex.getClass(), ex.getMessage(),
                LocalDateTime.now());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exo, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when causing the error, I do not get the ExcpetionObject returned:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-21T17:17:42.585+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "
...
}
```

Does anyone know how I get rid of the standard error message?

**Spring version: 2.4.4**

Comment: Double check first that  your code actually throws `NoSychSellerException`,

Comment: Does the stack trace contain `Could not find acceptable representation`?

Comment: @pirho Yes it is thrown, but the HTTP Status is an Internal Server Error and not a Bad Request

Comment: @DirkDeyne No the stack trace does not contain it